# Cannot access domain name with port number in IIS

Tags: web, iis, localhost

I've set up a new site in IIS. I can access it via IP, but can't via a specific domain.

`192.168.1.100:8001` is working

`test.test:8001` is not

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add. it shouldn't need to edit the hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.

Comment: If you neither use hosts to emulate DNS records nor set up a real DNS server, then how can you generate valid HTTP requests required by the binding? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: so there's no other way to make this possible? is that what you're saying?

Comment: Are you challenging the foundation of HTTP protocol stack? You didn't setup "everything" mandatory, so it won't work.

Comment: When you send a request via your web browser, it require to query either DNS server or hosts file for the destination IP address. If you didn't event create a host entry for domain test.test. your browser will never know should it deliver the request. So please at least add a host record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this `test.test` to your `hosts` file. The hosts file for Windows is located in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. Try to add your domain pointing to 127.0.0.1 like:

```
127.0.0.1 test.test
```